# Could not take picture with overlay

Tags: iphone, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller, screen-capture, gpuimage

I am using `UIImagePickercontroller` for take pictures. I have images under `UIScrollview`. When I click particular image from scrollview, the image will be subview of imageView. And the imageView will appear on cameraView of overlay. When I move particular image from top to bottom or anywhere on cameraView, then I need to take photo with overlay. But I am not able to capture photo with overlay.

code:

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];


    // Set the image picker source:
    // picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Hide the controls:
    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    picker.delegate=self;

    // Make camera view full screen:
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Insert the overlay:
     picker.cameraOverlayView = self.view;



    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    // Show the picker:
     [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,
                                   @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   nil);
}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    UIAlertView *alert;


    if (error)
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                           message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album."
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    else
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success"
                                           message:@"Image saved to Photo Album."
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    // [alert release];
}
```